# Can't Connect to MySQL Database after restarting computer. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

This code worked fine until I restarted my computer.

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>

  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fails</property>
  <property name="connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="connection.password">root</property>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

  <property name="show_sql">true</property>

  <property name="format_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

  <mapping class="com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey.Fail" />

 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

But after restarting my computer, my server instance had disappeared from MySQL Workbench. I created a new instance, the same way I did before (clicking next on each screen of the wizard, without changing default values).

The connection I had created previously was still there, but my table was gone. So I recreated it the same as before.

Now when I deploy my app and request my endpoint which pulls from the DB, I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Why can't I connect? My app code hasn't changed. I recreated my DB exactly as it was before.

Comment: That error message typically means you're trying to use the wrong password, or not providing a password at all...check to make sure you can login manually with the password you're using in your code

Comment: That error message typically means that you need to do a `GRANT PERMISSIONS` to `root` @ `localhost`